# Software for drawing and analyzing a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, math-software

I would like to know a good program for drawing graphs and analyzing them (finding Eulerian circuits, Hamilton cycles, etc.).  I would also like to export the drawing to Word.

Answer (score 11):

Why don't you try [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) -- it's free and should do as good a job anything else. You just type in

```
G = Graph (M)
```

for M an adjacency matrix to create your graph, then you can do

```
G.eulerian_circuit()
G.hamiltonian_cycle()
```

to find these things, and

```
plot(G)
```

draws your graph as a .png file which shouldn't be too hard to open in Word.

Comment: You can also use sage's notebook interface to "draw" the graph. For this you can use the command `graph_editor`.

Comment: The sage wiki also hosts [this](http://wiki.sagemath.org/graph_survey#Introduction) nice list of graph theory software. It might be a bit outdated but it is comprehensive.